# Kustomer api search endpoint (messages search) to return attachments as well

Tags: api, crm, kustomer

This is a **kustomer api** specific question.

Having Kustomer api endpoint `https://api.kustomerapp.com/v1/customers/search`, docs are [here](https://developer.kustomer.com/kustomer-api-docs/reference/customersearch).
I want to receive messages with attachments (attachment `name`, `contentType`, `contentLength`).

The body for this request (simplified version):

```
{
  "and": [
    {
        "message_channel": {
            "equals": ["email"]
        }
    }
  ],
  "queryContext": "message"
}
```

The problem here - the standard response does not include all the info about attachments that I need.
The question is - Is there any documentation on request body params `aggs` and `fields` (I think they may help)? Is it possible somehow to change the request body, so that message attachments are included in response as well?

I am trying to minimise the number of calls to kustomer api - get all the info in one go.

Thank you for your time.